# SQL sub query to retrieve total cost for each hotel

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, subquery

I'm trying to get my head around sub queries and I'm certain I don't actually know what I'm doing. I've got some code that pulls up the hotel names and room price, but the prices are showing the absolute total room price for all hotels together, not each hotel seperately.

```
SELECT hotelName, SUM(roomPrice) AS 'Room Price'

FROM hotel, room

GROUP BY hotelName
```

This code gives me this

[image: Hotel Name and Individual total room cost]

2360 is the total room cost over every hotel, I just need to change it to show the cost of each hotels total rooms, individually.

EDIT: Added a image of the database relations

[image: DATABASE]

Comment: well please show your original database and explain more your question,
let me guess do you need all total price of hotel ?

Comment: I'll edit in the designer preview of the database and its relations. I need it to show the total price of each hotel individually, instead of it just showing the hotel names and the total price of all the hotels combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT H.hotelName, SUM(R.roomPrice) as 'Room Price'
FROM hotel H
JOIN room R
ON H.hotelNo = R.hotelNo
GROUP BY H.hotelNo;
```

Comment: This worked, I just needed to change one bit.

FROM hotel H instead of FROM hotelName H

Thank you very much!

Comment: oh whoops sorry, I mistyped the table name.  I will edit

Answer (score 0):

```
select  SUM(b.roomPrice) AS 'Room Price' from hotel.hotel a, hotem.room b where a.hotelNo=b.hotelNo
```